# Enable Cut in Finder in OSX 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: macos, finder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it not possible to use the “cut” command to manipulate a file in the Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/why-is-it-not-possible-to-use-the-cut-command-to-manipulate-a-file-in-the-find)

I was fiddling with several settings a few days ago, and I'm pretty sure I did something that disabled the "Cut" option in Finder.

Anyone know where I can re-enable it?

Answer (score 4):

As @RobZolkos said in [his answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/12393/13414):

> It's not part of the Apple system to 'cut' files. The option is there
>   and becomes enabled when text is selected. But not files. [...]
>
> <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does the cut-and-paste for files
>   on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem - I use Total Finder, which adds Cut/Paste, and it wasn't running when I posted the question.

(I didn't know OSX doesn't have this by default).