# Cut-Paste files or folders on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, finder, snow-leopard, filesystem

The only way I know is to side the two source and destination folders, and drag and drop the files from one to the other. However in some cases we like to [cut them when only the source folder is  open, and paste them later](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12391/5472).

Is there anyway to move some files/folders on Mac OS X as easy as in Windows?

Comment: There are few utilities that I could not live without on osx, [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) is one of them (it brings tabs and cut-n-paste).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The shortcuts to Cut and Paste files or folders in Lion (or later) are:

- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to copy
- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to paste

Answer (score 4):

While you can copy (Command + C) and paste (Command  + V) files in OS X, the cut (Command + X) function is not supported.  What you can do however is choose whether to Move, Copy, or Create an alias when dragging and dropping files.

- Command + Drag and Drop = Move File
- Option (alt) + Drag and Drop = Copy File
- Option + Command + Drag and Drop = Create Alias

As a side note, when working with files all on the same Volume/Partition Move is the default action, there is no need to hold the Command Key.  Alternately, when working with files across two different Volume/Partitions, Copy is the default option and there is no need to hold the option key.  You can always tell what is about to happen by taking a look at the curser before you drop.  A green Plus (+) icon indicates that the file will be copied, the absence of this icon indicates a move.

If the Cut and Copy functionality is absolutely crucial to your workflow, then I suggest checking out [OnMyCommand](http://free.abracode.com/cmworkshop/on_my_command.html). It's a Unix and AppleScript Executor and if I recall, there are some user submitted scripts that will enable cut functionality for finder items.

Comment: You mixed the modifier keys up. Moving across logical volume boundaries requires the command key. Forcing a copy within a logical volume requires the option (alt) key.

Comment: @MacLemon You are absolutely correct sir, I don't know what I was thinking. I've edited my answer.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the free [Command X](https://apps.apple.com/app/id6448461551) app, which lets you press <kbd>Command-X</kbd> to cut files and <kbd>Command-V</kbd> to paste, like on Windows.